# How to Convert current date to hebrew date in Flutter or Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I want to Convert Current Date to Hebrew Date but didn't find any solution for it.

**Input**
11 March 2021

**Output**
27 Adar 5781

I tried this package : https://pub.dev/packages/shamsi_date but didn't work for my solution.

Comment: Is the package not converting the date right?

Comment: @Bach No i tried that package for conversion but this is not helpful for my solution because it convert Gregorian to Jalali.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using 2 ways:

- **Using Flutter Package :** https://pub.dev/packages/kosher_dart
- **Using API :** https://www.hebcal.com/home/developer-apis

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method `GetHebrewCalendar(HebrewMonthNumbering)` from this package: https://pub.dev/packages/time_machine